# Desktop folders not opening with Nautilus after upgrade from Ubuntu 18.04 to Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: upgrade, nautilus, default-programs

I upgraded my Ubuntu yesterday. Unfortunately, I've got a problem while trying to open Desktop folders: they now open with VSCode by default instead of Nautilus. When using Nautilus, the folders open normally.

I did not change any configuration file or default apps after updating it.

I really don't know what should I do. Any idea?